# Outputting Binary data in PHP

Tags: php

I trying to find function in PHP that can output the binary data.
The binary data is Not any image, text, audio data.  It just some plain binary stuffs that a program use and process.

What I should put into the header in term of output type.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do.  You just want to print out raw binary data?  `file_get_contents()` doesn't do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generic binary data MIME type is `application/octet-stream`.

If you have your binary data in a variable, you can simply write it out normally after setting the `Content-Type` header to such. (E.g. `echo`)

Comment: what if this does not work? (output->hex differently than string->base64->output->hex)